# Spinner not working vue.js

Tags: javascript, spinner, vue.js

I use this package: https://github.com/greyby/vue-spinner for showing a spinner.

```
<template>
  <pulse-loader :loading="loading" :color="color" :size="size"></pulse-loader>
</template>

<script>

import { PulseLoader } from 'vue-spinner/dist/vue-spinner.min.js';

export default {

  components: { PulseLoader },

  data () {
    return {
      loading: true,
      color: "black",
      size: "10"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

For some reason the spinner is not showing???!?! There are no erros in my console!

Comment: Try `components: { 'pulse-loader': PulseLoader }`

Comment: @RoyJ Thanks, but does not work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be importing from the `dist` folder.

Please, try importing the `vue` component source, doing as shown in the documentation:

```
import PulseLoader from 'vue-spinner/src/PulseLoader.vue'
```

Docs: https://github.com/greyby/vue-spinner#es6

---

**UPDATE**:

Considering Browserify restriction on applying transforms in files inside `node_modules`, then you could try the code snippet provided in the [mentioned GitHub issue](https://github.com/greyby/vue-spinner/issues/2):

```
var PulseLoader = require('vue-spinner/dist/vue-spinner.min').PulseLoader;
```

Comment: I'm using vueify aswel. If I do that I receive an error: https://github.com/greyby/vue-spinner/issues/2

Comment: Have you tried the code snippet provided in the mentioned GitHub issue? (see UPDATE in the answer)

Comment: Thanks, But what is actually the difference between `import { PulseLoader } from 'vue-spinner/dist/vue-spinner.min.js'
` and `import PulseLoader from 'vue-spinner/dist/vue-spinner.min.js'` ?

Comment: with `import { something }` we are trying to get the `something` property of the object provided by the imported script; with `import something` we are getting whatever is provided by the imported script and labeling it `something`

Answer (score 1):

The website I was working on had a custom CSS-file. It was missing the correct styles. Possibly because it was for an older version of Bootstrap.

Make sure that there is a definition for `.spinner-border` anywhere in your styles. If not, find out why not and fix it.

I have copied the style from the source-code of the [Vue examples](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/spinner#spinners) page for a quick fix.

```
@keyframes spinner-border {
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.spinner-border {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    border: .25em solid currentColor;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
    animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
}
```